# reCAPTCHA is not work during verifying if is filled correct

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have to use in my project reCAPTCHA during register. I go problem - even when user give correct input and fill captcha he is not registered. 0 errors appears just but in database is not append any data. Without reCAPTCHA it works perfect.
I tested code. In my opinion problem with `if($obj->success)` (line 29). The value of variable is not changing after this line. I tried search solution but I only get the same solution or for captcha.

Code:

http://pastebin.com/JZ5XvNyP

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because the value of `$a` and `$b` is not being set.

```
else if(empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        $a= $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $b = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $RegisterErrorMessage = 'Wypelnij captche !';
        }else
```

So `$a` and `$b` are only set if the recaptcha response is empty. Can you try printing the `$captcha_url`? It is most probably not set correctly.

So change

```
$captcha_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6Ld6LRM**YOUSECRETKEY***1VO&response=$a&remoteip=$b";
```

to

```
$a= $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$b = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$captcha_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6L****YOURSECRETKEY***&response=$a&remoteip=$b";
```

Comment: when I wanted echo it nothing happend I could not press register button. var_dump shows something like that:
https://www. google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?  secret=MYSECRETKEYHERE &response= &remoteip=

Comment: yup. That is because `$a` and `$b` are not being set.

Comment: I moved $a and $b after fetching results from base, url change but still nothing is append to the base

Comment: I've edited my answer. Can you try to echo the URL to google recaptcha now?

Comment: The `$a` and `$b` are being set only now. can you do  `var_dump` of the `$data` from the curl and `$obj` ?

Comment: I can not? after passing values to the variables i am trying to echo it or var_dump nothing appears. Ctrl+shift+I does not show any errors

Comment: `  if($data = file_get_contents_curl($captcha_url)){
                $obj = json_decode($data);`

after that, add `var_dump(obj); var_dump(data);`

Comment: Still is not any information displayed even 0 or null. 
Code:
http://pastebin.com/1pMchf3B

Comment: Can you do `$data = file_get_contents_curl($captcha_url)` instead of `if($data = file_get_contents_curl($captcha_url))` and check the var_dump

Comment: Still nothing, var_dump, echo display nothing. Isthis function file_get_contesnts_curl working? Everything mess up after callin these function.

Comment: I think that could also be the issue

Comment: Other function now is quiet better I can echo e.g. I am here but still it does not send any data to database. I had to change value from true to 2 because of [Notice] curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST no longer accepts the value 1, value 2 will be used instead error.
Code:
http://pastebin.com/4Y8RWQGr

Comment: Edit: In function after 53 line does not display $test value

Comment: Here is the problem, he always returns false does not matter if captcha is filled correctly

Comment: var_dump $res['success'] after $res = json_decode($curlData, TRUE); gives me null

Comment: var dump `$curlData` and check

Comment: var_dump $curlData blocked ablility to press register-button. I can press many times register and nothing would happend

Comment: when I treat $curlData as array $curlData[0] gives me null and $curlData[1] as I said before nothing happend

Comment: Try sending the data from something like Postman and put `var_dump` everywhere. So you can trace the flow of the program.

Comment: Finally worked. Another 5th approach. For others. We do not need any function to check that so all after 44 line you can delete. Instead of lines 28 and 29 write these :  
$verifyResponse = file_get_contents($url);
  $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
   if($responseData->success){
Full code here:
http://pastebin.com/B1P3Chxq
Part of solution taken from here:
http://www.codexworld.com/new-google-recaptcha-with-php/